# JDBC setMaxRows database usage

Tags: java, database, oracle, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to write a database independant application with JDBC. I now need a way to fetch the top N entries out of some table. I saw there is a `setMaxRows` method in JDBC, but I don't feel comfortable using it, because I am scared the database will push out all results, and only the JDBC driver will reduce the result. If I need the top 5 results in a table with a billion rows this will break my neck (**the table has an usable index**).

Writing special SQL-statements for every kind of database isn't very nice, but will let the database do clever query planning and stop fetching more results than necessary.

Can I rely on `setMaxRows` to tell the database to not work to much?

I guess in the worst case I can't rely on this working in the hoped way. I'm mostly interested in Postgres 9.1 and Oracle 11.2, so if someone has experience with these databases, please step forward.

Comment: Good question.  The javadoc says "Sets the limit for the maximum number of rows that any ResultSet object generated by this Statement object can contain to the given number. If the limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently dropped."  The way I read it, it implies that the JDBC driver could do the work.  I suspect its JDBC implementation dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will let the database do clever query planning and stop fetching more
>   results than necessary.

If you use

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1 LIMIT 10; -- slow without index
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 10;               -- fast even without index
```

[Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_select_the_top_n_rows_from_a_table):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1 DESC)
WHERE  ROWNUM < 10;
```

.. then only 10 rows will be **returned**. But if you sort your rows before picking top 10, *all* basically qualifying rows will be **read** before they can be sorted.

Matching indexes can prevent this overhead!

---

If you are unsure, what JDBC actually send to the database server, run a test and have the database engine log the statements received. In PostgreSQL you can [set in `postgresql.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT):

```
log_statement = all
```

(and reload) to log *all* statements sent to the server. Be sure to reset that setting after the test or your log files may grow huge.

Answer (score 2):

In direct answer to your question regarding PostgreSQL 9.1: Yes, the JDBC driver will tell the server to stop generating rows beyond what you set.

As others have pointed out, depending on indexes and the plan chosen, the server might scan a very large number of rows to find the five you want.  Proper server configuration can help accurately model the costs to prevent this, but if value distribution is unusual you may need to introduce and optimization barrier (like with a CTE) to coerce the planner to produce a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

The thing which could/may kill you with billion(s) of rows is the (highly likely) `ORDER BY` clause in your query. If this order cannot be established using an index then . . . it'll break your neck :)

I would not depend on the jdbc driver here. As a previous comment suggests it's unclear what it really does (looking at different rdbms).

If you are concerned regarding speed of your query you can use a `LIMIT` clause as well. If you use `LIMIT` you can at least be sure that it's passed on to the DB server.

Edit: Sorry, I was not aware that Oracle doesn't support `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue not long ago while executing a `SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <xyz>` query on SQL-based databases, with `setMaxRows` set to 1 million. Typically, our data remains below the 1 million mark, so we haven't encountered any problems. However, when a customer's data reached 36 million, these queries became the bottleneck for our ingestion process.

Initially, I believed that `setMaxRows` would automatically incorporate a `LIMIT` or `TOP` command based on the database connection type. To my surprise, this was not the case. Instead, `setMaxRows` only limits the queries received from the database and doesn't impose a limit on the database itself. Consequently, in our production environment, we were running `SELECT * FROM <table_name> ORDER BY <clause>` directly without any limit !

To address this, it's advisable to use `LIMIT` or `TOP` commands to restrict rows on the database side. Moreover, databases often perform optimizations when a limit clause is utilized. For instance, in our production scenario, running the query without a limit clause but with `setJdbcMaxRows` set to 10,000 took 15 minutes to fetch over 36 million records. However, by introducing the `TOP` command, the same query returned results in just 52 seconds.

It's worth noting that the official JDBC documentation explicitly mentions that `setMaxRows` limits the rows received from the database and doesn't impose a limit on the database itself.

[Click here to see Official JDBC Documentation Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjRyG.png)